# Take data from a form then change a word if it appears and print the result

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have got this form:

```
<form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">

    <div>
        <label for="name">Text:</label>
        <input type="text" id="data" />
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Input</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

What I want to do is take the data which has been submitted, then if the word 'good' is in the submitted text I need it to change to 'great' and then for it to be printed on the same or different page. It would be great if someone could help me do this with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/29kKX/9/

```
  <div>
        <label for="name">Text:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="data" value="good"/> 
  </div> 
    <div class="button"> 
        <button id="submit" onclick="replaceWord()">Submit</button>
   </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceWord(){
    var dataElem = document.getElementById("data");
    var data = dataElem.value
    data = data.replace("good", "great");
    dataElem.value=data;
    return false;
}
</script>​
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
    data=document.getElementById("data").value;
    if(data=='good')
    {document.getElementById("data").value='great';
    alert(document.getElementById("data").value);}
    return true;
}
</script>
<form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post" onsubmit="return fnc()">
```

Comment: You need to optimize your code. For example, in this example you force to go through DOM up to 3 times, which is bad.

Comment: I used 3 times just to show that the value is changed. You must use dom at least two times, Otherwise JQuery. It is easier to vote someone's answer negative rather than to read and understand why using such code

Comment: You're pretty wrong. Method getElementById searchs though DOM each time you call it. To avoid double-searching you must declare new variable, like: var foo = document.getElementById("data"); foo.value = "whatever";

Comment: Voting is easy. So is JS. Learn it.

Comment: @VladislavQulin while assigning foo it holds the state of the dom. So even though you do foo.value it is like accessing DOM. And have you tried using foo.value? use and see does it really change the value or not

Comment: @VladislavQulin In addition I am not hitting ant server. Its done on client side. So does it really costs too much using Dom? I know it is not

Comment: You can figure it out yourself by watching profile in your browser debugger (i like chromobug better). DOM optimization is number one optimization for your web application. Minifying HTTP requests isn't optimization, it's just proper design.